# Python: looping raw input

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to python and I am having trouble getting python to loop through a raw_input if there is no input and to loop through the question again until there is an input. Once there is an input move to the next question e.g.

```
again = None
while again == None:
    name = raw_input("Hello, please enter your name?: ")
    if name:
        print "Hello %s I am soandso" % name
again = raw_input("Please type a name: ")
```

I know this code is all jacked up. Just trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = None
while not name:
    name = raw_input("Hello, please enter your name?: ")
    if name:
        print "Hello %s I am soandso" % name
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code. You check "again == None" in the loop, but never change "again" value, so it always equals to "None" and loop never stops.

You can wrap input logic into a function and then ask multiple questions:

```
def get_value(question):
    while True:
        response = raw_input(question)
        if response:
            return response


answer1 = get_value('What is your first name? ')
answer2 = get_value('What is your last name? ')

print('First name: {}, last name: {}'.format(answer1, answer2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
again = None
while again == None:
    name = raw_input("Hello, please enter your name?: ")
    if name:
        print "Hello %s I am soandso" % name
again = raw_input("Please type a name: ")
```

This loop will never stop, because the again is always None